# Function pg_table_size does display real table size

Tags: postgresql

Does the pg_table_size function take into account dead tuples? If this is the case, do we have to run a vacuum each time to have precise information for the table's size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That function gives you the size on disk of the table and the out-of-line data (TOAST). This information is precise. Dead tuples and empty space are part of the table.

Note that `VACUUM` typically won't shrink the table size much, so running it will not make much difference.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz for your answer. I think pg_table_size ignores index. It's pg_total_relation_size that add index size.

Comment: You are right. I have fixed the answer.